# Color values in boxplot based on x-axis variable in ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
df = data.frame(cat = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each = 20), val = runif(80))
```

And an annotation dataframe like the following:

```
ann = data.frame(cat = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), col = c(34, 84, 23, 85))
```

I want to make a boxplot for each of these `cat`s along the x-axis, and the value in the data frame as the y-axis, but I also want to color each boxplot by the value in `ann$col` (continuous color mapping).

I can get the boxplot like the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = BACC)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.12)
```

But I am unsure how to color each boxplot by the category value.

How can this be done?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Like this? `ggplot(df, aes(cat, val, color = cat, fill = cat)) + geom_boxplot(width =.12)` - `color` affects the lines, `fill` changes the fill of the shapes.

Comment: Hi @[Jack Arnestad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8364914/jack-arnestad), please mark the answer as accepted if that solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few (minor) syntax errors in your data. Nevertheless, you are probably looking for this:

```
df <- data.frame(cat = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 20), val = runif(80))
ann <- data.frame(cat = ("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                  col = c(34, 84, 23, 85), 20)
library(dplyr) # inner_join comes with dplyr
df_ann <- inner_join(df, ann, by = 'cat') #join both into a three column dataframe 
#(cat, val, col) by mathcing column 'cat'.
ggplot(df_ann, aes(x = cat, y = val, fill = col)) +
geom_boxplot(width = 0.12) + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rainbow(9))
```

[image]